# SQL Server FOR XML PATH carriage return after each root node

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, for-xml-path

I am using FOR XML PATH in SQL Server 2014 to generate an XML file to send to one of our vendors.  Their system requires that each root node be separated by a carriage return / line break.  Here is the T-SQL code I'm using to generate it:

```
Declare @xmldata xml

set @xmldata = 
(SELECT a.StatementDate AS [stmt_date]
  ,a.CustomerID AS [student_id]
 ,'Upon Receipt' AS [due_date]
 ,a.TotalDue AS [curr_bal]
  ,a.TotalDue AS [total_due]
 ,a.AlternateID AS [alternate_id]
  ,a.FullName AS [student_name]
 ,a.Email AS [student_email]
 ,a.Addr1
 ,a.Addr2
  ,a.Msg AS [message]
  ,(
    SELECT b.StatementDate AS [activity_date]
          ,b.ActivityDesc AS [activity_desc]
          ,b.TermBalance AS [charge]
    FROM #ActivityXML AS b
    WHERE a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
    ORDER BY a.StatementDate
    FOR XML PATH('activity'),TYPE
   ) 
FROM #BillingStatement AS a
FOR XML PATH('Billing'))

select @xmldata as returnXml
```

This works great, but returns one long string with no separation between nodes at all.  (I would post an example but it would just look like a jumbled up mess in here.)

Anyhow, what we need is to generate a file where each `<Billing>` tag and contents within is placed on a new line after a closing `</Billing>` tag.  I would guess there's a simple solution, such as inserting `char(13)+char(10)` somewhere in the code, but I've been unable to get that working.  Is it possible or will I need to do it in another system?

Comment: try without PATH.. try AUTO or different option

Comment: Path is what gives the root node the tag of <Billing>, no?  That aside, I tried AUTO and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by putting that carriage return between root nodes? XML is not meant to be human readable, and any parser of it should be able to read it just fine without it.

Comment: The problem is not on your side actually: *Their system requires that each root node be separated by a carriage return* means, that they are using the wrong tool...

Comment: Shnugo is correct...this is a limitation of our vendor's system.  Poor design, I know, but we have no control over that of course.

Comment: The **pretty print** of XML is not supported natively within `T-SQL`. You might use a CLR method, a service or any kind of post processing with a physically stored file. You might open the XML from grid-results' xml viewer and copy-paste the output to a text editor. Don't forget to set the XML size for grid result to *unlimited*, if your XML is big.

Answer (score 0):

Based on responses here and research elsewhere, this is not possible using just T-SQL.  We would need to either copy / paste the output, or use another program to take the data and insert line breaks.

From @Shnugo - "The pretty print of XML is not supported natively within T-SQL. You might use a CLR method, a service or any kind of post processing with a physically stored file. You might open the XML from grid-results' xml viewer and copy-paste the output to a text editor. Don't forget to set the XML size for grid result to unlimited, if your XML is big."